# How to restore a Oracle Database if i only have the datafiles?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, recovery

My Oracle database Test server crashed, I have no rman backups but I still have the datafiles because they are on a SAN Storage, so if I have datafiles, how can I restore my Oracle database?

Comment: Define "crashed". Have you tried starting it up?

Answer (score 0):

> I just crashed my car at full speed into a brick wall.
> Can I just get back in and drive it away?

Really?  Wouldn't you rather get another car?  One that's working?

You have *no idea* what state your server is in, or *why* it crashed.
Depending on how badly "crashed" it is, you *might* be able to get it up and running again and do some diagnostic work to find out.
You might not.
Than again, you might not *want* to.  If you suspect that the server was compromised (hacked), your safest option would be to "burn" it and run up a new one.

You have *no idea* what state the server's *disks* are in.
Therefore, you have no idea what state your database is in.

It's *not* want you want to hear, but this is *precisely* why you ***must*** have Backups.  Not just of your database, either, but also for the server that you *run* it on and all the software (including the DBMS itself) that goes with it.

This is I.T.
"Stuff" happens.
You ***must*** protect yourself, ready for when it does.